# Github isn't recognizing my pushes

Tags: git, github

I'm pushing some commits through Terminal in Fedora but seems that GitHub isn't recognizing my user.

I saw the commits history to check what's wrong, then I realize that the commiter's name is different than my official GitHub's username.

Then I ask: what's the problem and how can I solve that?

I'm sure is something related to my user in .git or remote configurations. Anyway, I didn't found anything on the web that could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Set your email address](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-email-in-git) to the one registered to GitHub.com.  If you want to fix up the old commits, you'll have to [change history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/how-do-i-change-the-author-of-a-commit-in-git) and do a force push.  This is only recommended if you are working on a private repo.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your global Git settings so that they match your GitHub user settings (only the mail has to match, but you might as well set both):

```
$ git config --global user.name "Your name"
$ git config --global user.email "Your@mail.com"
```

By using the `--global` option you are telling Git to always use that information for anything you do on your system.

You can confirm that the settings were changed by doing:

```
$ git config user.name
Your name
$ git config user.email
Your@mail.com
```